# for loop condition always true

Tags: c, for-loop, types, range

I have a For loop in C:

```
u8 i;
for (i=0; i <= 255; i++)
{
    //code
}
```

Now the compiler complains that "comparison is always true due to limited range of data type"
I understand that 255 is u8 max but a for loop must have a condition. What should I put there then?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the loop? Iterate forever or stop at 255?

Comment: I want to loop from 0 -> 255 and stop as in the code

Comment: It is generally very difficult to iterate over *all* possible values of a given type, unless you have access to some strictly wider type (which is not guaranteed to exist).

Answer (score 7):

```
uint8_t i=0;
do {
    //code
}while(++i);
```

Answer (score 5):

what is `u8`? if it means 8-bit unsigned int, then 255+1 gives zero again, so the loop starts over again. you should use larger integer type. or use `do-while` as suggested in replies

Answer (score 3):

```
u8 i=0,iold;
do{
    //code
    iold=i++;
}while(iold<i);
```

Comment: Due to the `do`-`while` loop you don't actually need `iold`, you can just check if `i` becomes zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
u8 someFunction()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        // do something with i here and /or break
    }

    if (i == 256)
    {
        // loop ran completely without a break
    }

    return i; // will convert i to "u8" type (256 will become 0)
}
```

Comment: He then needs a return value of type `int` otherwise how to distinguish if it `break` at `i == 0` or if the loop was never `break`?

Comment: @ouah: I don't know what his intention is with the return value, he only mentioned that the return value was of type `u8`.

Comment: @dreamlax but `for` never ends here. what's the difference between `i<=255` and `i<256` ?

Comment: well, unless he breaks in the middle, in that case we would definitely know that `i` was not 256

Comment: @mangusta: Of course the `for` will end, `int` is guaranteed to be able to hold values larger than 255.

Comment: ah that's `int`, sorry : )

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop doesn't necessarily need a condition. If you want the loop to not have any condition at all, you can write:

```
for (i = 0; 1 ; i++)
```

or

```
for (i = 0; ; i++)
```

But beware that `i` will overflow after reaching 255, and start over back from zero each time.

If you don't want it to loop infinitely, then either place a `break;` somewhere inside the loop, or use an appropriate condition inside the condition field of the `for` loop.

And to be honest, I am not sure why your compiler is even complaining about a condition being always true...

Comment: re. “not sure why your compiler is even complaining”, the comparison is a loop condition involving a loop _variable_ – it seems unlikely that someone would write that code deliberately when they mean to create an infinite loop.

Comment: @Arkku Well, yeah, it would be thoughtful of the compiler to inform the user about these kind of situations; but apparently it does more than just informing about it, since OP came here complainingly asking about it. Nice if it is just an informative message, over-interference if it requires the user to take additional actions to continue anyway.

Comment: What makes you think they needed to “take additional actions to continue anyway”? The message is just a warning, it does not (by default) cause any kind of failure. And in any case the programmer needs to take the action of fixing the bug – which is what the question was about.

Comment: @Arkku Why such an aggressive manner all of a sudden? As I said, if the compiler is only informing, then fine. You can find the answer to your *unkind* question in the previous post, in the part beginning with *"since ..."*. Some people are weird, I must say...

Comment: I'm sorry for any offense caused, I'm only trying to succinctly point out the facts, i.e., there is a valid reason why the compiler would warn about this, and warnings do not (by default) equal an error that would require action, and in this case the warning indicated a genuine bug that needs to be fixed, which requires action. Nothing more, and nothing personal.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I put there then?

Use a larger type like  `int` type.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot do that as var i will be return of the function and it should be u8.

Comment: @Maluvel if you want to return `i` please show the whole function

Comment: Thanks, I will use a larger type and cast back to u8 in the return :)